# Many to one LSTM , softmax dimension error on Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to train a simple many-to-one RNN classifier using LSTM. My timesteps are 100 data points long with 7 features, I have a total of 192382 samples. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape = (100,7),name = 'LSTM',return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax',name = 'softmax_layer'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'],name='softmax')
model.fit(datax,datay,epochs=25,batch_size=128)
model.summary()
```

The model compiles fine with no error, however I can't fit the model. Here is the error that it returns:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected softmax_layer to have shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (192282, 100)
```

Does anyone have an idea why the softmax layer is returning a (192282, 100) matrix? Isn't return_sequence=False in the LSTM layer supposed to only give me one output per timestep?

Comment: Assuming you are classifying to 3 classes, you are passing the wrong value in datay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the softmax_layer returns (None, 3), because the size of last layer is 3.

Probably you want to fix it? So, in order to fix it you need the size of output layer (softmax_layer) should be equal to size of your label array (datay.shape[1]). In other words it must be equal to a number of classes.

Quick fix is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape = (100,7),name = 'LSTM',return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(datay.shape[1], activation='softmax',name = 'softmax_layer'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'],name='softmax')
model.fit(datax,datay,epochs=25,batch_size=128)
model.summary()
```